# Is it considered bad practice to force elements into place using margins and / or padding?

Tags: html, css, xaml, twitter-bootstrap

This practice is something I often come across, but rarely find likeable. Both when doing html, xaml or any other markup for that matter. I was just wondering if the use of these margins or padding techniques to force elements in their (seemingly) correct place is considered a bad practice?

Personally I prefer using grids, cols and cells when working with xaml, and when it comes to html I often use bootstrap for my work.

Every time I see this I end up discussing with the person having done work before me, why he / she has used margins to move an item into place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion using them isn't a problem or considered bad practice but you can easily use these properties poorly and abuse them. Typically most grid systems use padding to space of the columns usually between 10px - 30px, which is perfectly fine and then if you need to add additional padding and or margins to elements inside your columns that's fine but if you're using margin's to place elements in weird places like `margin: 500px 0 0 500px` then I consider that bad practice and you should reassess how you have structured your DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Well - when it comes to web - that is HTML and CSS - responsive design is the "new thing" so to speak, so elements float based on screen with and thereby media (result is one website for desktop, tablet and phone. It just floats differently).
Using bootstrap/grids is a common starting point these days.

So from that perspective, I'd say that margins/padding still have a place - but not as a "placement grid" so to speak. So yes, I'd say it's a "bad practice", despite not liking such dogmatic statements. 
Because in my view the real world situations we function under - then there might always be a reason for using even old tools from ones toolbox.

XAML I don't know about, so can't comment in that world.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, The usage of margin and padding to place a element is the most common method, This is due to the downgrade of using `<table>` element.

Now-a-days everyone prefers to use `<div>` element instead of using `<table>`. So that  using grids, cols and cells are reduced to almost 2%.